# Zoom, Crop and Cut videos iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video, zooming

I have a small video clip in my iPhone Application on which I wish to carryout the following operations -

1. Zoom - I should be able to zoom in and out the video by pinching gestures.
2. Crop - I should be able to Crop the video length after increasing/decreasing its speed.
3. Cut - I should be able to drag a window on any part of the video and cut that piece of video which is within the window as a separate video.

Since the video size is very small (less than a minute), all I can think of is converting the video into images by extracting each frames and then carry-out the above operations. 
Can anyone suggest a better idea?

Thanks

Comment: I have converted the videos into set of images and am trying to carry out the above operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy an fast way to achieve these operations would be to use the [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). You should be looking at the `GPUImageMovie` class in `GPUImage` to edit movies in iOS. The framework already comes with a set of filters that you can use to carry out the operations that you need. See [this section](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#filtering-and-re-encoding-a-movie) for more details on how to edit videos using GPUImage.

In short, you first create a `GPUImageMovie` object:

```
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
```

Then create some filters and apply the filters to the object.

```
cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] init];
[movieFile addTarget:cropFilter];
```

You can add more filters in the chain by adding targets to the previousFilter in your chain. Finally, when you are ready to convert the video, do this:

```
NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];
[pixellateFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had stumbled upon GPUImageFilter. However, I was not sure if I could carryout all the 3 operations mentioned above.